# Delete element from nested hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a two dimensional hashes in Ruby.

```
h = { "a" => {"v1" => 0, "v2" => 1}, "c" => {"v1" => 2, "v2" => 3} }
```

I would like to delete those elements from the hash, where value 1 (`v1`) is 0, for example, so my result would be:

```
{ "c" => {"v1" => 2, "v2" => 3} }
```

I wanted to achieve this by iterating trough the hash with `delete_if`, but I'm not sure how to handle the nested parts with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
h.delete_if { |_, v| v['v1'].zero? }
#=> {"c" => {"v1" => 2, "v2" => 3}}
```

As @TomLord says, it also may be variant, when `v1` can be not defined or equal to `nil`, in this case, it would be better to use `v['v1'] == 0`

Comment: Will the nested hashes always contain a `'v1'` key, and will it always map to `Numeric` object? If not, it would be safer to use `== 0` instead of `.zero?`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Hash#value?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-value-3F) in your block to check if *any* of the values in the nested hashes equal `0`:

```
hash.delete_if { |k,v| v.value? 0 } #=> { "c" => { "v1" => 2, "v2" => 3 } }
```

Comment: the OP seems to only care about `v1` in the sub hash so if `v1 == 1` and `v2 == 0` then this solution is inaccurate

Comment: @engineersmnky True, I've just added some explanation. I will leave the answer up as the OP may still find it useful.